# Create constraints for list variable in CVXPY

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

In CVXPY I created a variable called "contracts", which includes 126 elements.

```
contracts = cp.Variable(126, integer=True)
```

I have two pandas series (1x126) with min and max values for each of the 126 elements (called "min_contracts" and "max_contracts").
In order to massively add constraints for each of the 126 elements of my variable, I tried the following:

```
constraints = [min_contracts <= contracts, contracts <= max_contracts]
```

but I get the following

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'parameters'.
```

What could I try?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I need to transform the pandas series into lists.

Adding the following fixed the issue

```
min_contracts = min_contracts.tolist()
max_contracts = max_contracts.tolist()
```